# How can I determine that these functions are linear transformations?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

How can I determine if the following functions are linear transformations?
$$T: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \space T(x)=x^2$$
$$T: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \space T(x)=-2x$$
$$T: \mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \space T\Big(\begin{bmatrix}
x\\ 
y
\end{bmatrix} \Big) = x^2+y^2
$$

I know the definition of a linear transformation, but I can not apply it here.

Comment: I have to prove it with variables

Comment: To show that an  identity you want are true you have to "prove it with variables" - ordinary algebra will work. To show that it is false a numerical counterexample is enough. Just try each of these to see if the algebra works. If it doesn't, convince yourself with a numerical example.

Comment: I want to show if they are true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A map $T: \mathbb{R}^n \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ is linear iff $T(x + y) = T(x) + T(y)$ for all $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $T(\lambda x ) = \lambda T(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$.

Consider your first map, say $T_1$. Then $T_1(2) = 4 \neq 2 = 1 + 1 = T_1(1) + T_1(1)$, so $T_1$ is not linear.

For your second map, say $T_2$, note that

$$T_2(x + y) = - 2(x + y) = - 2x -2y = T_2(x) + T_2(y)$$

and

$$T_2(\lambda x) = -2 \lambda x = \lambda \cdot (-2x) = \lambda T_2(x)$$

for all $x, y , \lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, hence $T_2$ is linear.

Now what can you conclude about the linearity of your third map, when looking at $T_1$?

Answer (score 0):

A linear transformation has two conditions

> Let $V$ and $W$ be two vector spaces and let $T$ be a function with
>   domain in $V$ and range in $W$. Then $T$ is a linear transformation if
>
> $1. \forall x,y \in V, \space T(x+y) = T(x) + T(y) $
>
> $2.\forall x \in V, \lambda \in \mathbb{R}, \space T(\lambda x) = \lambda
>  T(x) $

We are going to (dis)prove
$$T_3\Big(\begin{bmatrix}
x\\ 
y
\end{bmatrix} \Big) = x^2+y^2 \text{ and } T_1(x)=x^2
$$

**Example $1$**

Let $\vec{x} = \begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\ 
x_2
\end{bmatrix}
$ and $\vec{y} = \begin{bmatrix}
y_1\\ 
y_2
\end{bmatrix}
$. By definition, we have $$T_3(\vec{x}+\vec{y}) = T_3\Big(\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 +y_1\\ 
x_2 +y_2
\end{bmatrix} \Big) = (x_1 +y_1)^2 + (x_2 +y_2)^2
$$
and
$$T_3(\vec{x}) + T_3(\vec{y}) = T_3\Big(\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\ 
x_2
\end{bmatrix}\Big) + T_3\Big(\begin{bmatrix}
y_1\\ 
y_2
\end{bmatrix}\Big) = x_1^2 + x_2^2 + y_1^2 +y_2^2
$$

As the first condition does not hold already $\big( (x_1 +y_1)^2 + (x_2 +y_2)^2 \neq x_1^2 + x_2^2 + y_1^2 +y_2^2 \big)$ we can conclude that the function $T_3(x)$ is not a linear transformation.

**Example $2$**

By definition, we have $$T_1(x+y) = (x+y)^2$$ and $$T_1(x) + T_1(y) = x^2 +y^2$$

Again, the first condition does not hold $\big((x+y)^2 \neq x^2 +y^2\big)$, so it is not a linear transformation.

Let me know in the comments if you have trouble (dis)proving the other equation. But I think these examples suffices to understand the concept.

Comment: Thank you, what about the first one?

Comment: @HANA Added to my answer.